# Android Facebook SDK 4.0 external logout

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

[image]

I've succesfully updated my Login code for FB SDK 4.0. Initially, I used this code to logout from Facebook from an external dialog.

```
if (Global.getActiveSession() != null) {
        Session.getActiveSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation();
    }

    Session.setActiveSession(null);
```

But with the new FB SDK 4.0, there is no way I use this. I've tried using

```
  LoginManager loginManager = LoginManager.getInstance();
    loginManager.logOut();
```

but got the following error which I cannot explain.

```
       at com.facebook.internal.Validate.sdkInitialized(Validate.java:99)
        at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.<init>(LoginManager.java:70)
        at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.getInstance(LoginManager.java:81)
        at    com.ababab.abab_name_changed.common.util.CommonUtils.fbLogout(CommonUtils.java:676)
```

Comment: Can you provide the sample code for login using facebook 4.0

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```

Works for me.

I think you'll have to call

`FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());`

before you ask the LoginManager to logout.

Comment: This is correct. You should do sdkInitialize before calling ANY methods in the Facebook SDK.