# FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext()) Deprecated

Tags: android, facebook

I'm integrating facebook SDK in my app as an option to login for the users. But recently I have started getting `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext())` as Deprecated

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
```

So after hustling for long I was able to find the solution to this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41884349/facebooksdk-sdkinitialize-context-is-deprecated/41884415#41884415

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So according to the latest facebook documentation we now don't need to initialize the facebook SDK and it automatically gets invoked. So now `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext())` can be deleted.

Answer (score 3):

Simply do not write this line of code in your class

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
```